# Vinyl garage floor coating

Tags: garage, vinyl-flooring

I was passing by a home, and noted that the garage flooring had a shiny vinyl coating, looking as if it were waterproof.

Does anyone know of this product used? And how long it lasts.

Comment: Probably epoxy and is very durable

Comment: ^^ that, but you should know that proper preparation is everything with those  kits...

Comment: I have epoxy coated several garage floors works great 20+ years on my shop , prep is critical a good acid rince to clean the floor (10% muriatic and water) . 1 caution if you spill antifreeze it becomes very slippery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same type of epoxy paint for a basement floor:

[Rust-oleum EPOXYSHIELD Garage Floor Coating](http://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/epoxyshield/garage-concrete-floor-coatings/garage-floor-coating)

There are a lot of different versions as well as professionally applied products. If you want to do it yourself:

[Concrete, Basement & Garage Floor Paint at The Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Paint-Concrete-Basement-Garage-Floor-Paint/N-5yc1vZbd13)